# Function that converts any text into number

Tags: functions, reference-request, infinity

Years ago I've seen on the Internet a mathematical function that converts any letter/word, i don't remember exactly, into a number. The idea is that the function generates infinitely different output, and anything can be found/located on this infinity, like [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem). Now I cannot find this function, could you please remind it?

**Update**

The Q is not about some text encodings for software or smth like this. There probably was a couple of functions – one function describes a plane discrete space with `X` defined on `(-∞;+∞)`, and `Y` defined on `[0; N]`, like an infinite-wide picture of pixels. And another function takes a string and returns a number `Z` which is the start (a value of the `X` axis) of the string in the picture of the first function. I don't remember where I saw this function, probably it was YouTube or some elective course the longest time ago.

Comment: ASCII,Unicode, UTF-8 are some of the things depending on if you're only considering mostly latin english or you care about other alphabets.

Comment: First you have to define how large the alphabet is. If you have $N$ possible letters , you can convert the text into a number in the base-$N$-system and then convert this number into a non-negative integer in base $10$. This will however give very large numbers, even for rather small texts.

Comment: @kingW3 I'm an experienced software engineer, of course I know about ext encodings  The Q is about mathematical function, not a programmable table.

Comment: @AivanF. Any lookup table is also a function. It produces an output for any input in its domain. Any deterministic algorithm that produces an output from an input is also mathematically a function.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I understand, I simply mean that the function I remember was not made with any table usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit:] Actually, after your edit, I think you might be looking for a different thing, namely [Tupper's self-referential formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula).

I'll leave my original answer in place, since it's a similar concept.

---

> I think you're looking for [Champernowne's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant), which is the decimal number
> $$
> 0.1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6\,7\,8\,9\,10\,11\,12\,13\,14\,15\,16\,17\,18\,19\,20\,21\cdots$$
>
> For any given natural number $n$, it appears somewhere in the decimals of this constant (by definition, since the constant just lists all natural numbers as its decimals).

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely the **Tupper's self-referential formula**, thank you! 

Answer (score -2):

Well assuming I'm understanding correctly, there would be lots of different way to go about this. One would be to turn each letter into an index of the alphabet, like $a=1,b=2,c=3,\dots$, and then concatenate the numbers, so $abc$ becomes $123$, and so on. You could even just use the already in-place Unicode system that has uniquely numbers for each symbol, and then just concatenate those the same way. This would guarantee a unique number for each and every possible combination of letters or symbols.

Edit: There weren't any comment when I started typing this, so I see now people have already mentioned Unicode now

Comment: How could we distinguish this way "aa" from the $11$-th letter , when the number is $11$ ?

Comment: If "abc" becomes "123", what do "lc" and "aw" become?